# Laravel - Is the cache:clear command will clear config cache also?

Tags: laravel, caching

I use Laravel 5.8, and as we know, there are 3 type of cache in Laravel

- Config cache (`php artisan config:cache`)
- Route cache (`php artisan route:cache`)
- View cache (`php artisan view:cache`)

.

So, in my Laravel app, I use `Cache::remember('mycachetoday', $seconds, function(){})`...

In order to clear the `mycachetoday`, i must run `php artisan cache:clear`, right?

But I wonder if I run `php artisan cache:clear`, will the config, route, and view cache be cleared also?

Thanks

Comment: no, it will not clear them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```sh
php artisan config:cache
```

The config cache file will be store in `bootstrap/cache` directory.

When you run

```sh
php artisan cache:clear
```

It will only clear the datas that you store by `Cache`. The config cache file still in `bootstrap/cache`.

After you run `php artisan config:clear`, the file will be deleted from `bootstrap/cache`.

Check the [ClearCommand source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Cache/Console/ClearCommand.php), there is no code that delete any config/route/view cache file in `bootstrap/cache`, and only clear the application cache.

```php
/**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->laravel['events']->dispatch(
            'cache:clearing', [$this->argument('store'), $this->tags()]
        );

        $successful = $this->cache()->flush();

        $this->flushFacades();

        if (! $successful) {
            return $this->error('Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.');
        }

        $this->laravel['events']->dispatch(
            'cache:cleared', [$this->argument('store'), $this->tags()]
        );

        $this->info('Application cache cleared!');
    }
```

Check the [ConfigClearCommand source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConfigClearCommand.php), it will delete the config cache file.

```php
/**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->files->delete($this->laravel->getCachedConfigPath());

        $this->info('Configuration cache cleared!');
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

To clear everything, you can do `php artisan optimize:clear`. This will result in:

```php
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
```

Regards!

Comment: Although it is not related with this question...but....Wow anyway..nice to know this...i just knew about this..thanks...i upvote your answer

Comment: Thanks @SyamsoulAzrien, as you said, this is not specific to the question but this command is really usefull when developing and publishing the app.